# R: Automate exporting Excel documents pulling from separate lists of dataframes

Tags: r

I am looking for a way to pull same named dataframes from separate lists and export them into their own excel documents.

My data is much larger than this but here's a small rundown of where I'm stuck:

I have three dataframes:

```
df1
 Company   ID      Charge
[1] A      1234     100
[2] A      1234     150
[3] B      5678     100
[4] C      2468     200
[5] C      2468     200
```

```
df2
 Company   ID      Location
[1] A      1234     NY
[2] A      1234     NY
[3] B      5678     CHI
[4] C      2468     LA
```

```
df3
   Company  ID    Combined Summary
[1] A      1234        250
[2] B      5678        100
[3] C      2468        400
```

I ran a split function which created three seperate lists of dataframes based on column value :

```
List_A <- df1 %>%
  base::split(., .$Company)

List_B <- df2 %>%
  base::split(., .$Company)

List_C <- df3 %>%
  base::split(., .$Company)
```

I am trying to come up with a for loop or apply function that will automate the process of pulling same named dataframes from each list and then put those dataframes into seperate spreadsheets. I would also like the naming convention to be the same for each speadsheet (Spreadsheet A, Spreadsheet B ect.) I have attached a few images of what I'm hoping the final output will look like.[Spreadsheet A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vt3tN.png) [Spreadsheet B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qeyd6.png)  [Spreadsheet C](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ygp3.png). I would really appreaciate any suggestions/advice. Thanks!

Update--
I just want to thank everyone for your help on this.
I have one more question. What if I had an uneven list of data frames? Here is the example:

```html
DF <- data.frame(Company=c('Alpha', 'Alpha', 'Alpha', 'Beta', 'Beta', 'Gamma', 'Epsilon'),
                 Location=c('NY', 'NY', 'CHI', 'LA', 'CHI','LA', 'LA' ),
                 ID=c('1234', '1234', '1234', '5678', '5678', '2468', '2468'),
                 Charge=c(25,25,51, 60,60, 15, 15))

DF2 <- data.frame(Company=c('Alpha', 'Alpha', 'Beta', 'Beta', 'Delta', 'Delta', 'Delta'),
                  Location=c('NY', 'NY', 'CHI', 'LA', 'CHI','LA', 'LA' ),
                  ID=c('1234', '1234', '1234', '5678', '4567', '4567', '4567'),
                  Charge=c(25,25,51, 60,60, 15, 15))


DF3 <- data.frame(Company=c('Alpha', 'Alpha', 'Beta', 'Delta', 'Delta','Delta','Delta'),
                  Location=c('NY', 'NY', 'CHI', 'LA', 'CHI','LA', 'LA' ),
                  ID=c('1234', '1234', '1234', '5678', '4567', '6789', '6789'),
                  Charge=c(25,25,51, 60,60, 15, 15))
```

If I split by company name using the solution below, I recieve an error becuase the company names aren't in each dataframe. Is there a way to automate exporting the dataframes even if not every exported workbook will have 4 spreadsheets?

```html
`list(
  DF, DF2, DF3
) %>%
  purrr::set_names(paste("SpreadsheetA"), paste("SpreadsheetB"), paste("SpreadsheetC"), paste("SpreadsheetD")) %>% 
  purrr::map(~ split(.x, .x$Company)) %>%
  purrr::transpose() %>%
  purrr::iwalk(~writexl::write_xlsx(.x, file.path(path, paste0("results_", .y, ".xlsx"))))`
```

Comment: Would it be an option for You not to split the dataframes by a column value but just bind them all together into one bigger dataframe and then just filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use `purrr::transpose`. To this end

1. Put your dataframes in a `list`.
2. Name the list according to the desired spreadsheet labels.
3. Use e.g. `lapply` or `purrr::map` to split the data by `Company`.
4. Use `purrr::transpose` to convert the list of splitted dataframes into a list per company.
5. Finally, loop over the list to export it to excel.

Using a minimal reproducible example based on `mtcars` where I use `cyl` as "company" identifier:

```r
library(purrr)
library(writexl)
library(readxl)

df1 <- mtcars[c("cyl", "mpg")]
df2 <- mtcars[c("cyl", "hp")]
df3 <- mtcars[c("cyl", "disp")]

path <- tempdir()

list(
  df1, df2, df3
) |> 
  purrr::set_names(paste("Spreadsheet", LETTERS[1:3])) |> 
  purrr::map(~ split(.x, .x$cyl)) |> 
  purrr::transpose() |> 
  purrr::iwalk(~writexl::write_xlsx(.x, file.path(path, paste0("results_", .y, ".xlsx"))))
```

As a check, importing one of the just exported excel files confirms that it contains the data for one company or `cyl` from the three original dfs stored as separate spreadsheets:

```
fn <- file.path(path, "results_8.xlsx")

sheets <- readxl::excel_sheets(fn)
names(sheets) <- sheets

purrr::map(sheets, ~ readxl::read_excel(fn, sheet = .x))
#> $`Spreadsheet A`
#> # A tibble: 14 × 2
#>      cyl   mpg
#>    <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1     8  18.7
#>  2     8  14.3
#>  3     8  16.4
#>  4     8  17.3
#>  5     8  15.2
#>  6     8  10.4
#>  7     8  10.4
#>  8     8  14.7
#>  9     8  15.5
#> 10     8  15.2
#> 11     8  13.3
#> 12     8  19.2
#> 13     8  15.8
#> 14     8  15  
#> 
#> $`Spreadsheet B`
#> # A tibble: 14 × 2
#>      cyl    hp
#>    <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1     8   175
#>  2     8   245
#>  3     8   180
#>  4     8   180
#>  5     8   180
#>  6     8   205
#>  7     8   215
#>  8     8   230
#>  9     8   150
#> 10     8   150
#> 11     8   245
#> 12     8   175
#> 13     8   264
#> 14     8   335
#> 
#> $`Spreadsheet C`
#> # A tibble: 14 × 2
#>      cyl  disp
#>    <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1     8  360 
#>  2     8  360 
#>  3     8  276.
#>  4     8  276.
#>  5     8  276.
#>  6     8  472 
#>  7     8  460 
#>  8     8  440 
#>  9     8  318 
#> 10     8  304 
#> 11     8  350 
#> 12     8  400 
#> 13     8  351 
#> 14     8  301
```

Comment: Seems like the output is not splitted properly by `cyl` levels

Comment: @JakubMałecki What do you mean by "not splitted properly by cyl"?

Comment: All spreadsheets in Your output have the same value for `cyl`. But I understand the intention of the author that one spreadsheet collects data from all partial datasets with the same value, or am I wrong? "(...) pulling same named dataframes from each list and then put those dataframes into seperate spreadsheets"

Comment: @JakubMałecki From my understanding of the question, i.e. "export them into their own excel documents." and also what the images show (i.e. only data for one company per sheet), the OP want's to export data for each company aka "cyl" to a separate excel file. Otherwise there would be not reason to split the data by company and we could simply do `list(df1, df2, df3) |> write.xlsx(...)`. But I was also a bit confused about the naming of the spreadsheets which seem to indicate that we want sheets per company. (:

Comment: Ah, right. I misunderstood the question. Thanks for discussion. I'll need to fix my answer as an alternative to Yours.

Comment: Hi everyone. Thank you very much for your help! The first solution resolved my problem, and the only change I made was modifying the sheet names. (purr::set_name("Company A", "Company B" ect.).

Answer (score 0):

You may try this approach. I'll use a list of data.frames created from mtcars dataset in my example, namely `dfs_by_cyl`. But of course You'll replace it with Your own list. In the end of my answer I'm giving the code for full reproducibility.

```
# determine unique names across all partial datasets
unique_names <- lapply(dfs_by_cyl, names) |> unlist() |> unique()

# combine the partial datasets by unique names (reshaping the list)
combined_by_value <- lapply(unique_names, function(nm) {
  lapply(dfs_by_cyl, `[[`, nm)
}) |> setNames(unique_names)

# store it in an xlsx file
for (k in seq_len(length(combined_by_value))) {
  out_file <- tempfile(fileext = ".xlsx")
  sheet_names <- names(combined_by_value[[k]])
  for (i in seq_len(length(combined_by_value[[k]]))) {
    d <- combined_by_value[[k]][[i]]
    xlsx::write.xlsx(d,
                     file = out_file,
                     sheetName = paste("Spreadsheet", sheet_names[i]),
                     append = TRUE)  
  }
  cat(out_file, "\n")
}
```

For reproducibility only - create example datasets:

```
library(rsample)
init_split <- initial_split(mtcars, strata = "cyl", prop = 1/3)
df1 <- training(init_split)
rest <- testing(init_split)
second_split <- initial_split(rest, strata = "cyl", prop = .5)
df2 <- training(second_split)
df3 <- testing(second_split)

# helper
split_by_value <- function(dfs, value) {
  dfs_by_cyl <- lapply(dfs, function(i) {
    split(i, i[[value]])
  })
}

dfs_by_cyl <- split_by_value(list(df1, df2, df3), "cyl")
```